# How to create a tag field with Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry, I really dunno how to describe those things where they usually use when entering several words. Each words will be ajax'd and if exist it will change into a button with an x for removal. It's even use here at the bottom when entering the tags :D.

[image]

my question is what kind of form GUI is that, is that exist in bootstrap?

thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those items are often called tags and you may find a nice solution for bootstrap here:

[Bootstrap Tag Helper](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

In the example you are showing there is also used a kind of autocomplete textbox.

Comment: thank you :D. I want to accept but it ask me to wait in 11 minutes haha

Comment: the autocomplete type box is using typehead.js